# How to delete a C++ object being drawn by OpenGL?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have a list(vector) of objects, which are continuously being drawn on screen. During the glutMainLoop, I have this glutTimerFunction update, which periodically checks if an object goes out of the screen boundaries, and if it is so, it deletes the object. This is giving a segmentation fault.

Here is the class ->

```
class bullet
{
   private:
   public:
     void update();
     bool check()
     {
        if(y>=box_len/2)
        {
        return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
     void draw();
};
vector <bullet*> bullets;
```

Here is the update function ->

```
void update(int value)
{
  for( typeof(bullets.begin()) it= bullets.begin(); it!= bullets.end();it++)
  {
    if((*it)!=NULL)
    {
      if(*it)->check())
      {
        delete *it;
        bullets.erase(it);
      }
    }
  }
  glutTimerFunc(10, update, 0);
}
```

Registerd with glut in main() as

```
glutTimerFunc(10, update, 0);
```

Comment: What's in `bullet::~bullet` (the destructor)? Also you can rewrite `bullet::check` as `{return y >= box_len/2;}`

Comment: How is `tr` defined? Also, it looks like you're missing some code around this line: `(*it)->check())`. It's presumably meant to be an `if` condition?

Comment: Is it generally safe to modify a container that you're iterating through?

Comment: @user1118321 that will invalidate the iterator you are using generally, vector's erase returns a new one you can use though

Comment: Your title is misleading. OpenGL has a concept of objects (e.g. Texture Objects, Vertex Buffer Objects, Vertex Array Objects) independent of the C++ language. Since OpenGL operates asynchronously with the CPU there are times when a Vertex Buffer Object is going to be used in a pending GL command... you are free to delete that object even before that command finishes because OpenGL takes care of synchronization on objects it owns behind the scenes. *Frankly, this question has nothing to do with OpenGL*

Comment: @datenwolf-Its empty!

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - If I am not wrong, you mean that even though the display function will be continuously calling bullet::draw() and the update function bullet::update(), I can still delete the bullet object? 
Well this surely helps a lot! Thanks :)

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield - I corrected the mistakes.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - It is giving a segmentation fault in the call to bullet::check() function made by the update function. Are the callbacks registered with glutTimerFunc() also synchronised?

Comment: Well, first of all, GLUT is not part of OpenGL. It is a framework that is loosely layered on top of OpenGL, that makes creating and managing OpenGL render contexts simpler (though a lot less flexible). And as far as objects go, I really was not talking about the things you are constructing and destroying in C++... unfortunately the GL API and programming languages both have things called objects. This question pertains only to language-level objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the element being deleted is the last element, the iterator becomes the next element ( bullets.end() in this case). The increment at the end of the for loop, causes it to become something invalid and was the reason for the segfault.

Repaired code ->

```
void update(int value)
{
  for( typeof(bullets.begin()) it= bullets.begin(); it!= bullets.end();it++)
  {
   if((*it)!=NULL)
   {
     if(*it)->check())
     {
      delete *it;
      bullets.erase(it);
      if(it==bullets.end())
        break;
     }
   }
  }
  glutTimerFunc(10, update, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `tr` is some sort of foreach macro?

In which case, removing an item from your `vector` will invalidate the iterator.

Use `it = bullets.erase(it);` to ensure your iterator stays valid.